# how to filter out lines between two timestamps in python

Tags: python, regex

I have following issue, i have a log file that i want to read line by line, but to reduce the lines i want to filter out the lines that are between two timestamps!

example in awk:

```
find all between two patterns: pattern1 = 2012-10-23 14, pattern2 = 2012-10-23 16
awk '/2012-10-23 14/{P=1;next}/2012-10-23 16/{exit} P' server.log
```

or with egrep and one pattern:

```
egrep "2012-10-23 (1[4-6]:[0-5][0-9])" server.log
```

The above awk line would give me only the lines between those two timestamps.

How can i do it in python without executing any system command or awk, grep..., but only with python regular expression

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one to one translation from your awk code:

```
with open('yourFile') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for l in lines:
    if l.startswith('2012-10-23 14'):
        p=1
    elif l.startswith('2012-10-23 16'):
        p=0
        break
    if p: print l
```

this will start the output when the 1st line starting with `2012-10-23 14 ...` matched, and stop printting when the 1st line starting with `2012-10-23 16..` matched. (same as your awk codes)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the @Kent post will work only if we assume that the timestamp is at the beginning of your line. With your AWK / egrep code you ask for something more generic.

Following code should work:

- independently where the searched pattern within the line is located
- independently on if the lines in the log are properly sorted (though this is highly assumable ;-) )
- as non-blocking generator yielding the results as they are being processed without unnecessary memory allocation.
- has more generic code construction, in case you want to make further modifications.

  ```
  import re 

  def log_lines(yourFile, regexp):
    rxp = re.compile(regexp)
    with open(yourFile) as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
        if rxp.search(line): 
          yield line

  for line in log_lines("yourFile", "2012-10-23 1[4-6]"):
     print line
  ```

Stay with python, it is adictive ;-)

Comment: this lists only lines matching the `regexp`, but lines between the "borders" could be anything, and they need to be printed out. like a log file of jboss/weblogic, those stacktrace output may not contain timestamp, but they sit between the "border lines". his awk one-liner does it. also his awk is gonna print only first trunk of text, then exit.

Comment: You are both right, I just forgot to mention it in my question that it is important to print all lines between the two timestamps even if they don't have the timestamp, like Kent mentioned. Martin, has also his point that many times the log files are not sorted properly. I my case the timestamp is always at the beginning of the line, if at all. I will combine both of your suggestions, because I want also to reduce the mem. alloc. Thanks again!